# How to find time difference between two time zones using moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to find the time difference in seconds between two time zones using momentjs.

`oldTZ = moment.tz("America/New_York").format('Z');
 newTZ = moment.tz("Asia/Calcutta").format('Z');`

This gives the value of `-04:00` and `+5:30`; a difference of 9.5hrs.

I would then like to divide these down to seconds and subtract them `msNewTZ-msOldTZ` to give me: `34200`

Now, I cannot subtract these two because they are strings. As a result I am not sure how to manage this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just use `parseInt()` to convert the strings into numbers?

Comment: no because they have (+) and (-) in them which needs to keep. Also ":" is not an int.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I managed to get it:

```
var newTZ= moment().tz("Asia/Calcutta");
var oldTZ = moment().tz("America/New_York");
difference = newTZ.subtract(oldTZ, 'seconds')
difference = difference.format("HH:mm");
sec= difference.split(":");
timeInSec = (sec[0] * 60 * 60) + (sec[1] * 60);
console.log(timeInSec);
```

You have to use `.format(...)` after your time calculations are complete. You also cannot use diff(), you must use subtract(). After the 4th line its simply a matter of doing basic math.

Comment: Hi ran this code this is giving me 15 hours and not 9 hours 30 minutes as it should be ... can you explain or prepare a example